# Rails - Sending array through Postman Params not permitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to upload images in rails using Carrierwave. but I'm having a problem in permissions

This is my controller:

```
class PhotoController < ApplicationController
  def upload_multiple
    render json: {
      status: params[:photos].inspect,
    }, status: 200
  end

  def photos_params
    params.require(:photos).permit(:photos => [])
  end
end
```

Im trying to inspect to debug. The result of inspect is:

```
"status": "<ActionController::Parameters {\"1\"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fe8b1ae7d50 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/4w/32p7h9rx2mjf9_m60852pn2m0000gn/T/RackMultipart20190406-1520-1r799qx.jpg>, @original_filename=\"IMG_1303.jpg\", @content_type=\"image/jpeg\", @headers=\"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\\\"photos[1]\\\"; filename=\\\"IMG_1303.jpg\\\"\\r\\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\\r\\n\">} permitted: false>"
```

What Im passing in postman is as follows:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

Rename the parameter from `photos[1]` to `photos[]`. I can't say is this possible in postman, but in terms of html it should be `<input type="file" name="photos[]">` (and the form `enctype` is `multipart/form-data`), since it's looks like you're sending a hash, then change `params.require(:photos).permit(:photos => [])` to `params.permit(photos: [])`.

Comment: Tried this, same result

Comment: Do you mean `status: params.permit(photos: []).inspect` shows that `photos` parameter is still unpermitted? Could you show raw http request with parameters.

Comment: Inspecting params gives the following: <ActionController::Parameters {\"1\"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fe8b1ae7d50 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/4w/32p7h9rx2mjf9_m60852pn2m0000gn/T/RackMultipart20190406-1520-1r799qx.jpg>, @original_filename=\"IMG_1303.jpg\", @content_type=\"image/jpeg\", @headers=\"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\\\"photos[1]\\\"; filename=\\\"IMG_1303.jpg\\\"\\r\\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\\r\\n\">} permitted: false>"

Comment: Try to rename parameter from `photos[1]` to `photos[]`. I can't say is this possible in postman, but in terms of html it should be `<input type="file" name="photos[]">` (and form type is `multipart/form-data`), since it's looks like you're sending a hash.

Comment: This worked can you add this to answer, and Ill accept it :) 
And thanks a lot for the help